# Get array of tokens in an optional capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that would match the following patterns using `String.match`:

```js
"rgb(252, 246, 253)" // ["252", "246", "253"]
"hsl(12, 23%, 43%)" // ["12", "23%", "43%"]
"myfunc(342, 2341%, 0.5%)" // ["342", "2341%", "0.5%"]
"(723, 456a, 123)" // ["723", "456a", "123"]
"12 4324 0.6%" // ["12", "4324", "0.6%"]
"hello world word3" // ["hello", "world", "word3"]
"keep, writing, more, words, asmuch" // ["keep", "writing", "more", "words", "asmuch"]
"fn(hello world word3)" // ["hello", "world", "word3"]
```

The scope must be within the optional (first) brackets - if they don't exist, the whole string can be considered. Within that scope, just the comma/space separated tokens need to be matched.

I've tried different approaches, notably `/\(([^()]*)\)/g` and `/[^\s(),]+/g`, but it still did not quite get there.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but you can try this one `/\(([^)]+)\)/`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't fallback to the entire string I think - https://regex101.com/r/RNAqdj/1

Comment: `.split(/.*\(|[), ]+/).filter(Boolean)` would pass all your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if there is not an opening `(` ahead.

```
[^,)(\s]+(?![^(]*\()
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pHZ42r/2) (the `\n` in multiline demo is to stay in line)

---

- `[^,)(\s]+` [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) characters not in the list
- `(?![^(]*\()` looks after each match if no opening parentheses is *ahead*